# HTML zoom overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have a jsp page as shown below

[image: JSP Page]

When I zoom this page my  tags and buttons are overlapping editor area, How can I prevent this?

[image]

I don't want buttons to come over editor even on zoom.

My CSS code

```
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 20%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    #widnow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 72.5%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 3%;
}
#title_bar{
    background: #FEFEFE;
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
}
#button{
    border:solid 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 23px;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
 #box{
    height: 250px;
    background: #DFDFDF;
}
 #ul{
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: where is your code dear ???

Comment: Hold on! I'll filter the servlet calls and input validation for my code and then paste it.

Comment: paste the css mate..!! or atleast create a fiddle or a link to your site..!!

Comment: @SajadLfc  check it out!

Comment: Thank You. It worked. Just checked it. I'd be glad if you could further clarify what made the difference, I am new to UI stuff.

Comment: :Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. The document and other elements behave like the absolutely positioned element does not exist.

Absolutely positioned elements can overlap other elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to change all the `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;` in your css and div style..!!

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa2XQ/)